# How to analyze pbs_server, pbs_mom log entry of Server and Worker Node

Tags: pbs, torque

How can I analyze these log entries, I want to understand what is the format of these log entries?

> 1) PBS_Server;LOG_ERROR::Cannot assign requested address (99) in
>   send_job, send_job failed to d23818f7 port 15002
>
> 2) pbs_mom;LOG_ALERT::mom_server_valid_message_source, bad connect
>   from 210.56.24.244:1023 - unauthorized server

Answer (score 0):

The name in `/var/spool/torque/server_name` on the compute hosts and on the server should match, and should resolve to the same address. If it doesn't, check `/etc/hosts`, `nsswitch.conf`, and DNS to get that worked out.

EDIT #1: also, I'd be sure to put the output of the `hostname` command on the server into the `server_name` file on all machines.

EDIT #2: also be aware that `$pbsserver` in `/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/config` on the compute nodes will override the value in the `server_name` file. (So it's best not to use `$pbs_server`.)